# Греческий алфавит запрограммирован что ли в Свифт?

Tags: swift4

Греческий алфавит запрограммирован что ли в Свифт? И имеет свои цифры? Пожалуйста объясните мне.

```
(1, "aplha") < (2, "beta")
//истина, так как 1 меньше 2.
//вторая пара элементов не учитывается
(4, "beta") < (4, "gamma")
//истина, так как "beta" меньше "gamma".
(3.14, "pi") == (3.14, "pi")
//истина, так как все соответствующие элементы идентичны
```

Пример из книги. Скажите пожалуйста, на примере сравнения кортежей, первое сравнение где

```
(1, "aplha") < (2, "beta")
```

в первую очередь первые элементы я так понимаю сравниваются а затем вторые элементы? Здесь ясно тогда, если это так.

А второй пример

```
(4, "beta") < (4, "gamma")
//истина, так как "beta" меньше "gamma".
```

тут сравниваются после первых элементов уже вторые я так понимаю элементы и здесь меня удивляет то, что алфавит греческий есть в Свифт как я понял?

И странно то, что в числовом значении уже идет сравнение `beta` и `gamma`, хотя записаны через скобки как обычный текст. Кто то вообще использует греческий алфавит в числовом значении в Свифт среди русскоязычных людей?

Объясните подробно как это работает?

Comment: Подсказка: `"b" < "g"`.

Comment: @D-side выходит тут дело и не в beta и gamma? а только в первых двух буквах что-ли? по английскому алфавиту?

Comment: Ну да. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тексты в упорядочены *лексикографически*, как в *обычных* (не компьютерных) словарях:

Сравниваются отдельные соответствующие буквы *одна после другой, пока не получится разница* (или не исчерпаны буквы из одного или обоих сравниваемых текстов).

Когда нет разниц и исчерпаны буквы из обоих текстов, тексты равны, иначе первая разница становит отношение `<` или `>`.

Пример:

```
"thanks" < "think"
```

потому что первые две буквы (`t` и `h`) тот же самые, но в третьей разница:

```
a < i,
```

потому что в (латинском) алфавите буква `а` находится ранее, чем буква `i`.

Это не имеет *ни какой связь с греческим алфавитом* - строка `"alfa"` или `"Donald"` тот же самого качества (из символов *латинского* алфавита).

---

С парами, тройками, и т.д. это аналогично, как вы правильно заметили:

```
(4, "beta") < (4, "gamma")
```

Сравниваются соответствующее элементы, пока не возникнет разница. (В первых элементах разницы нет, также сравнение продолжается - и во вторых элементах (`"beta"`, `"gamma"`) уже разницы есть (а именно сразу в первой букве: `"b" < "g"`).

---

Да, возникает ещё вопрос, *как сравниваются отдельные буквы / символы*?

Это завит от *конкретной программы* (или языка программирования):

- В самом простом случае *нет ни какого выбора* (для пользователя или программиста)  - порядок букв *данный и неизменяемый*, обычно для их численного представления в соответствующей таблице / кодировании, как например [ASCII](http://www.housecomputer.ru/technology/encoding/acsii.html), [ISO/IEC 8859-5](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-5) или [Юникод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) - см. также [Таблица символов Юникода](https://unicode-table.com/ru/).
- Более разработанные программы и языки программирования используют так называемые **Collating Sequences** (*сортирующие последовательности*) и пользователь может выбрать *одну из готовых* (или неявно использовать *стандартную*).
- В наиболее разработанных средах может пользователь даже создать собственные сортирующие последовательности.

Примеры сортирующих последовательностей (неполные):

- Сначала все прописные буквы в алфавитном упорядочении, затем строчные, затем цифры (`А < Б < В < ... < Я < а < б < в < ... < я < 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < ... < 9`)
- Прописные и строчные буквы имеют тот же смысл (`А = а < Б = б < В = в < ... < Я = я`)